# "The return type 'String?' isn't a 'void', as required by the closure's context."

Tags: flutter

The error I am receiving states "The return type 'String?' isn't a 'void', as required by the closure's context."    the variable "_desc" is a string.

```
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Caption'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      return value!.isEmpty ? 'Description is required' : null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      return _desc = value;
                    },
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ditch the `return`. Just assign `_desc`.

Comment: decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Caption'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      return value!.isEmpty ? 'Description is required' : null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _desc = value;
                    },